# 128 x 128 NSImage looks bad in a 32 x 32 NSImageView

Tags: macos, nsimage, nsimageview

I'm trying to present this example image inside a NSImageView:
[image]

The image size is 128x128 and the NSImageView is 32x32.

I've created a new macOS project and placed that image inside NSImageView. The default settings gave me the blurry image below. I've also tried many scaling options such as
`scaleNone`, `scaleProportionallyUpOrDown`, `scaleProportionallyDown` but the result still looks blurry:

[image]

Changing the NSImage size to 32x32 will fix the problem but I'm looking for the cause of this scaling issue.
Creating a new project in Xcode for iOS with `UIImageView` & `UIImage` with the same sizes will display the image correctly. (I'm aware that there's a world of difference but I wanted to make sure that the image isn't the problem)

[image]

What am I missing?